# TopNav Menu Navigation Example - Icon not shows on first menu

Tags: html, css, angular, navigation, icons

I've followed [Dynamic nested topnav menu](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-topnav-menu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) to create a navigation bar.

It was working perfectly until that I've tried to add an icon to the parents menu by change the code iconName: 'close' to iconName: 'arrow_circle_down' for DevFestFL.

The icon just cannot be displayed, but it works fine on its children.

```
 {
  displayName: 'DevFestFL',
  iconName: 'arrow_circle_down',
  children: [
    {
      displayName: 'Speakers',
      iconName: 'arrow_circle_down',
      children: [
        {
          displayName: 'Michael Prentice',
          iconName: 'person',
          route: 'michael-prentice',
          children: [
            {
              displayName: 'Create Enterprise UIs',
              iconName: 'star_rate',
              route: 'material-design',
            },
          ],
        },
```

---

Thank you Agustin L. Lacuara

I have installed the package, and I have tried Angular Material Icons.

```
displayName: 'Reports',
  iconName: 'arrow_downward',
  children: [
    {
      displayName: 'Content History Report',
      iconName: 'arrow_downward',
      route: 'reports/content-history'
    },
    {
      displayName: 'Drive History Report',
      iconName: 'article',
      route: 'reports/drive-history'
    }
  ]
```

However, it only worked for child menu.

[Icon is not working for parents menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eMej.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- Handle branch node buttons here -->
  <span *ngIf="item.children && item.children.length > 0">
    <button
      mat-button
      [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu.childMenu"
      [disabled]="item.disabled"
    >
      {{ item.displayName }}
      <mat-icon>{{ item.iconName }} </mat-icon>
    </button>
    <app-menu-item #menu [items]="item.children"></app-menu-item>
  </span>
```

One line was missed from the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using icons from Angular Material Icons. Here there is a cheatsheet that might help you, it did in some projects for me.

https://jossef.github.io/material-design-icons-iconfont/

Comment: To clarify: some icons showing and other not, might be a clue that icon's name which is not being displayed is missing in where icons are looked for

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and sorry for accidently edited your post.